# How to find value of the given integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $\Omega=\{z\in \mathbb C:Im z>0\}$ and let $C$ be the smooth curve lying in $\Omega $ with initial point $-1+2i$ and final point $1+2i$.

Find the value of  $\displaystyle \int _C\dfrac{1+2z}{1+z}dz$.

Since $C$ is a smooth curve joining $(-1,2)$ to $(1,2)$ so the point $(-1,0)$  lies in the curve.

So $f(z)=\dfrac{1+2z}{1+z}$ has  a pole at $(-1,0)$.

On applying the Residue theorem we get value of integral to be $-2\pi i$ but the answer is wrong and it is given as $4-0.5\ln 2+i\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find an antiderivative for $(1+2z)/(1+z).$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint : (In which point you are wrong)**

You can't apply Residue theorem , as $C$ is NOT  **closed** curve.

Apply line integral only to solve the problem. Put $z=x+2i$ , $\,dz=\,dx$ and take limit of the integration  as $x=-1$ to $x=1$.

Comment: thanks for the info ;I got that wrong;